# Possible syntax problem in boot sector in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, boot

I'm writing a 64 bit boot sector for my os and i found this piece of code (use this link for reference https://github.com/gmarino2048/64bit-os-tutorial/blob/master/Chapter%203/3.1%20-%20The%20IDT/bootloader/boot.asm). this code doesn't work for me. is this a valid nasm syntax? as far as i understand there are 2 things wrong.

1. we make a call to a label without a ret instruction
2. the label syntax is wrong because `equ` is used for defining a constant but not like this

```
; BEGIN SECOND SECTOR. THIS ONE CONTAINS 32-BIT CODE ONLY

bootsector_extended:
begin_protected:

[bits 32]
```

here i cleared some irrelevant functions such as manipulations with vga buffer and includes from other files. the following code is the continuation of the file.

```
; Define necessary constants
vga_start:                  equ 0x000B8000
vga_extent:                 equ 80 * 25 * 2             ; VGA Memory is 80 chars wide by 25 chars tall (one char is 2 bytes)
style_wb:                   equ 0x0F

; Define messages
protected_alert:                 db `64-bit long mode supported`, 0

; Fill with zeros to the end of the sector
times 512 - ($ - bootsector_extended) db 0x00
begin_long_mode:

[bits 64]

mov rdi, style_blue
call clear_long

mov rdi, style_blue
mov rsi, long_mode_note
call print_long

call kernel_start

jmp $

%include "long_mode/clear.asm"
%include "long_mode/print.asm"

kernel_start:                   equ 0x8200              ; Kernel is at 1MB
long_mode_note:                 db `Now running in fully-enabled, 64-bit long mode!`, 0
style_blue:                     equ 0x1F

times 512 - ($ - begin_long_mode) db 0x00
```

the code fails specifically at the call to `kernel_start`

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? 1) you can `call` without `ret`, that's not a syntax error but I don't even see where you think the `ret` is missing 2) the colon is normally not used but at least my version of nasm accepts it.

Comment: @Jester my nasm eats it too. The code is supposed to load the kernel at 1 mb, as far as i understand, but it "crashes" after `call print_long` and everything starts over again (the whole program is a busyloop, as you can see in the link. i want to debug it with gdb but i lack the expirience to do it in qemu

Comment: Update: Need code setting up 64 bit transition

Comment: Where do you switch to 64 bit mode

Comment: @Joshua I added some code (once again, you can refer to the original from the link above). As far as I understand, the only thing which is relevant to the switch from 32 to 64 is the directive `[bits 64]`?

Comment: @fuz see comment above

Comment: I did get the tutorial OS to run under Bochs, finally. I'm not too familiar with nasm syntax, but apparently `call kernel_start` is valid, with `kernel_start` set to `0x8200`. The disassembly looks like: `call .+477 (0x0000000000008200)`. No idea why it says the kernel is at 1MB, but the kernel image is jumped to at `0x8200` and the disassembly of the ELF kernel image shows that address is `kernel/src/cpu/isr_defs.asm:isr_common`.

Comment: @sj95126: in NASM syntax `call <numeric literal or constant>` treats the number as an absolute address, and computes the right rel32 to reach it from here.  In a flat binary, that's based on `org`.  (In `-felf64` or whatever, current nasm fills in the rel32 assuming the start of the current section is address 0, it seems.  But yasm uses an `R_X86_64_PC32` relocation to get the linker to fill in a proper rel32.)  Confusingly, `nasm -l/dev/stdout` to make a listing doesn't show actual machine-code bytes, it shows the computed target address, so I had to use `ndisasm -b64`.

Comment: @sauce So you do not switch to 64 bit mode.  The boot sector is executed in real mode (i.e. 16 bit mode).  You have to write code to switch to 64 bit mode, a `[bits 64]` directive just makes the assembler emit 64 bit code, which the processor is going to execute as 16 bit code since you haven't switched.  This is not going to work the way you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer invalidated by newer code. It would be a delete answer except for the still-useful info in the comment chain you can pick out.

Comment: It's not jmp vs. call that's important, is it?  Rather far vs. near.  You can do a far `call` if you want.  (And if your main returns with `retf`, it can return to this infinite loop.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I made some adjustments, but I'm petty sure that that `ret` would only work by accident.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know / think of that possible problem with width of ret addr.  In any case, a far `call` *would* get you to `main` in the correct mode, although with the stack maybe misaligned.  But just writing `jmp rax` wouldn't.  (So good update, except 64-bit mode *does* have `CALL m16:64` https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call.  What's missing is any equivalent for [jmp](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp) or call `ptr16:32` *direct* absolute jump/call.  Your only option is memory-indirect jump, call, or push/`retf` for doing a far control-transfer from 64-bit mode.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Ok then need more code from OP. Annotated as such.

Comment: A little confusing what's being said here. Once you enable long mode, the very first thing you need to do is a far jump to load the new code segment descriptor in `cs`. If you were in real-mode, you do a 16-bit far jump. If you were in protected mode, a 32-bit far jump. Either way, you're not running 64-bit instructions until you reload `cs`.

Comment: @sj95126: I think OP ran the `ldgt` instruction and is trying to write the `jmp` instruction. This leaves him in the very interesting state of decoding 64 bit instructions from a 16 bit IP.

Comment: @Joshua: But that's my point, it's not that state. Just loading a new GDT doesn't mean those descriptors are in use. Whether you're running 16-bit or 64-bit instructions is determined by the `D/B` and `L` bits in the code segment descriptor. Until you force a reload, the old values are still in the hidden/cached portion of `cs` and you're not decoding 64-bit instructions yet.

Comment: @sj95126: Then how on earth did he get through two subroutines written in the wrong bit-ness?

Comment: @Joshua: we don't know what happened because we haven't seen all the code. But if it's doing exactly what's in that tutorial, it enables protected mode and immediately does a far jump, then it enables long mode and does another far jump. So I think the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @sj95126 yes, i'm doing exactly what's in the tutorial. as i said, the emulation 'crashed' on the call to the `kernel_start`. i thought that the problem might be with the syntax (i wish i knew how to use gdb with qemu so i can know for sure)

Comment: It's possible `[bits 64]` machine code happened to partly decode ok in 16-bit mode.  x86 is little-endian, so `call rel32` will decode as `call rel16` with the same small offset, and on return the `00 00  add [bx+si], al` from the high 2 bytes of the rel32 the assembler emitted probably don't fault in real mode.  Same for `mov r32, imm32` vs. `mov r16, imm16` with small values.  (@sauce, use a debugger to single-step through your bootloader.  Ideally the debugger built-in to Bochs; it knows about segmentation and the current mode, so should show you how the CPU will really run each insn)

Comment: @PeterCordes OP just plain did not switch to 64 bit mode anywhere.

Comment: @fuz: ok, that makes sense.  Then what I said probably *is* how execution "got through two subroutines" in the wrong bit-ness.

Comment: @fuz: At this point I am believing the source code link contains the source in entirety. I spent a long time path-verifying it. I don't understand the failure mode anymore but I think he actually switched to 64 bit code. In any case, that's no real explanation either because trying to explain the fault on the call instruction baffles me. I don't have one single hypothesis anymore.